# Can't get form to hide in JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Having this problem with trying to get a form to hide in Javascript.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Timer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">  
        <div id="time">00:00:00</div>   
        <form id="myform">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="box" placeholder="00:00:00" onkeypress="checkBox(event)">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my JS:

```
function timer(time) {
    document.getElementById("myform").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("time").style.display = "inline";

    var interval = setInterval(function () {    
        if (time == 0) {        
            time = 299;     
        } else {        
            var newTime = timeFormat(time);     
            document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = newTime;        
            document.title = newTime;       
            time--;     
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function checkBox(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var string = document.getElementById("box").value;
        var numTest = string;

        if (string.length != 0) {

            var numOfColons = string.split(":").length - 1;
            var hr = 0;
            var min = 0;
            var sec = 0;

            if (numOfColons == 2) {     
                numTest = numTest.replace(":", "");
                numTest = numTest.replace(":", "");     
                hr = string.substring(0, string.indexOf(":"));
                string = string.replace(string.substring(0, string.indexOf(":")+1), "");
                min = string.substring(0, string.indexOf(":"));
                string = string.replace(string.substring(0, string.indexOf(":")+1), "");
                sec = string.substring(0, string.length);
            } else if (numOfColons == 1) {          
                numTest = numTest.replace(":", "");         
                min = string.substring(0, string.indexOf(":"));
                string = string.replace(string.substring(0, string.indexOf(":")+1), "");
                sec = string.substring(0, string.length);   
            } else if (numOfColons == 0) {          
                sec = string;       
            }

            hr = parseInt(hr);
            min = parseInt(min);
            sec = parseInt(sec);

            if(/^\d+$/.test(numTest)) {     
                var totalSec = hr*3600 + min*60 + sec;
                if (totalSec > 0) {             
                    timer(totalSec);            
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function focus() {
    document.getElementById("box").focus();
}

function timeFormat(time) {
    var sec = time % 60;
    var totalMin = time / 60;
    var min = Math.floor(totalMin % 60);

    var string = "";

    if (min == 0 && sec < 10) {
        string = "0:0" + sec;
    } else if (min == 0) {
        string = "0:" + sec;
    } else if (sec < 10) {
        string = min + ":0" + sec;
    } else {
        string =  min + ":" + sec;
    }

    return string;
}
```

Note that I am not using a button to trigger the form submission, I am simply using a onkeypress event to detect if the user hit the enter button (I wanted a cleaner design). Whenever the timer function is called, the text box flickers like it turns off for a second, than it comes back on in an instant. I have no idea what the problem is. I also have gotten no errors in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure what you are trying to achieve but from looking at your code, Hitting enter results in the page being reloaded, so I can't get to see the result.

I would however suggest you use jQuery to hide show your results, since you are already calling the script

```
    $('#myform').hide();
    $('#time').show();
```

Comment: I tried using jQuery's hide function instead and it still didn't work.

Comment: It does turn it off, but you realize the form being submitted means the page is reloaded, and by default, the form is set to display. 

So the alternative is to remove the form tags completely, and use `$('#box').hide();`

In this case, I have 

`<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="time">00:00:00</div>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="box" placeholder="00:00:00" onkeypress="checkBox(event)">
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line of code. It turns the form off for a split second, which causes the blinking effect to occur. Simply remove this or comment it out.

```
document.getElementById("myform").style.display = "none";
```

If you want to hide the form, use jQuery's `$('#myForm').hide()` function. It's similar to `<form id="myform" style="display:none;">`

You could also try this:

```
<input type="text" id="timeInputBox" autocomplete="off" id="box" placeholder="00:00:00" onkeypress="checkBox(event)">
```

With this:

```
document.getElementById('timeInputBox').style.display = "none"; // JS
```

Or use this:

```
$('#timeInputBox').hide(); // jQuery
```

You may also want to move the jQuery `<script>` tag up higher in your `<head>` block. It needs to go before your call to your external `<script src="javascript.js"></script>` tag. Then you can use the $ and all of these functions from [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com) in your .js file.

Comment: Moved up the jQuery <script> tag and commented out that line you said to, and I used jQuery's hide function, and it still didn't work.

Comment: I'm confused... you want me to create another text box using the same functions and see if it works?

Comment: No. I wasn't suggesting that you should create another text box. I was simply showing you that you can put an id into that input field & hide it using jQuery's .hide() function.